# How to integrate a custom form and add/edit/delete on wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

i want to create a custom form with some fields that i could  add/edit/delete  on database

how integrate my form with wordpress?

do you know a website ,that have a tutorial about this process ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plugins that allow you to create custom forms ([cformsII](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/)), and with some additional PHP knowledge you can retrieve the data using their API. I found this tutorial that quickly goes through [installing, configuring and retrieving data](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Wordpress_installation_and_configuration#Using_the_CformsII_plugin_to_collect_and_display_data) from this plugin. That same page also listed some additional forms plugins that are worth looking at.

Another option is to do this using HTML and PHP without the use of a plugin. The following link will give you some insight in how to start and some code that can get you started:

http://www.paulmc.org/whatithink/2009/02/05/using-wordpress-templates-to-create-forms/

Note: There is a plugin called [Formidable](http://blog.strategy11.com/formidable-wordpress-plugin/) but only the [Pro](http://formidablepro.com/) version allows you to easily retrieve the data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really involved question, so it shouldn't be asked here.

P.S. Not specific to WordPress but http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: thanks for reply, but i want to create this form in wordpress
how to integrate with wordpress??